# Java Maven + Eclipse + junit: package not found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I have a project on eclipse in which junit is included as dependency in pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The project compiles well and dependency is properly resolved. 
I created my test folder under /src directory and added some class.
However, the namespace org.junit cannot be found on my code until I "Fix project setup" to include JUnit4 Maven Dependency.

I think this should not be necessary since I included the dependency on the pom.xml. Right?

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I have seen this behavior. I used to comment <scope> test</scope> and maven downloads it and then uncomment.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work

Comment: Does your project build on plain command line?

Comment: What is precisely the structure of your test directories?
After src/test?

Comment: /src/test/java/my/package/structure/MyClassTest.java (is the same structure under /src/main/java for the tested class)

Comment: That looks good. Another question (already asked by @khmarbaise): does the project build via command line?